# Json String Mapping containing a field having big decimal field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jackson

There is a scenario in which we are trying to convert a JSON string to a map, but during the conversion, values having big decimal value is truncated and converted to double. We need the actual big decimal value instead

Example

```js
{
    "amount":600.014545218781256,
    "currency": "SATS"
}
```

this is the request
but the **amount** gets truncated to **600.0145452187812**.

We tried using object mapper, but as the incoming data is a string, we weren't able to use the features of object mapper such as :
`objectMapper.configure(JsonWriteFeature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS.mappedFeature(), true);`

Comment: If the json is always having similar attribute and type, why don't you use a DTO class having BigDecimal value? Or will it be different

Comment: We can't use a DTO class as we our request is not static or pre defined, our request is based on versions, i.e request r1 for version v1 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson takes the value as Double. This behavior can be modified to obtain a BigDecimal object instead of a Double during deserialization. Enable the feature on the ObjectMapper object.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       String json = "{\"amount\":600.014545218781256,\"currency\":\"SATS\"}";
       mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS,true);

       Map<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
       System.out.println(map);
   }        
}
```

Comment: you can try this  I got below output
{amount=600.014545218781256, currency=SATS}

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.